# SPARQL - Unable to filter by country

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I know this is an easy question to answer, but I have been googling this for a few hours without success.  Why does the following SPARQL being entered in http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ not return anything?

```
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?country ?city ?city_name ?country_name
WHERE {
?city rdf:type dbo:City .
?city foaf:name ?city_name .
?city dbo:country ?country .
FILTER(?country=dbpedia:Canada).
?country foaf:name ?country_name .
}
LIMIT 200
```

I also tried -with the same results (i.e. none)

```
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?country ?city ?city_name
WHERE {
?city rdf:type dbo:City .
?city foaf:name ?city_name .
?city dbo:country ?country .
?country foaf:name ?country_name .
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?country_name),"EN") && ?country_name="Canada")
}
LIMIT 200
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for filters for an equality.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 

SELECT ?country ?city ?city_name
WHERE {
    ?city rdf:type dbo:City ;
          foaf:name ?city_name ;
          dbo:country ?country .

    ?country foaf:name "Canada"@en .

    FILTER(langMatches(lang(?city_name), "en"))
}
ORDER BY ?city_name
LIMIT 100
```

Test : http://linkedwiki.com/query/Filter_cities_by_country_with_DBpedia

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with some further digging.

To get the first query digging, I was using the wrong prefix.  I needed to use `<http://dbpedia.org/Resource>` not the ontology one.  This comes pre-defined in snorql - but it didn't actually have a prefix.  But with some fiddling the following worked.

```
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?country ?city ?city_name ?country_name
WHERE {
?city rdf:type dbo:City .
?city foaf:name ?city_name .
?city dbo:country ?country .
FILTER(?country=:Canada).
?country foaf:name ?country_name .    
}
LIMIT 200
```

As for matching on name, apparently you can't just match on a literal when using `foaf`.  You need to add the language tag:

```
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?country ?city ?city_name
WHERE {
?city rdf:type dbo:City .
?city foaf:name ?city_name .
?city dbo:country ?country .
?country foaf:name ?country_name .
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?country_name),"EN") && ?country_name="Canada"@en)
}
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: there is no need for a filter on the language in your second query when you already set the label to a specific value

Comment: and you could match on the literal without a language tag by using `str` function: `filter(str(?country_name) = "Canada")` - clearly, this is much slower as it has to process all countries names instead of using a database index